# Receiving "NameError: name 'Pin' isn't defined" when running python code on an ESP32

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, esp32

I am using a raspberrypi4 with an ESP32 and am attempting to collect data from my HW-390 capacitive soil sensor. I was following the code from [this website](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#installing-micropython):

```
from machine import ADC

adc = ADC(Pin(32))          # create ADC object on ADC pin
adc.read()                  # read value, 0-4095 across voltage range 0.0v - 1.0v

adc.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)    # set 11dB input attenuation (voltage range roughly 0.0v - 3.6v)
adc.width(ADC.WIDTH_9BIT)   # set 9 bit return values (returned range 0-511)
adc.read()                  # read value using the newly configured attenuation and width
```

To read values from my soil sensor. When I run the program I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pythonsoil.py", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'Pin' isn't defined
```

I have the data wire going through a 1k Ohm resistor then to D32 aka GPIO32 so I assume the problem is with the code itself.

What do I need to do to change the code so that it gives readings?

Answer (score 1):

You missed to import `Pin`

Your code should look like

```
from machine import ADC, Pin

adc = ADC(Pin(32))          # create ADC object on ADC pin
adc.read()                  # read value, 0-4095 across voltage range 0.0v - 1.0v

adc.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)    # set 11dB input attenuation (voltage range roughly 0.0v - 3.6v)
adc.width(ADC.WIDTH_9BIT)   # set 9 bit return values (returned range 0-511)
adc.read()
```